# form array value changes angular

Tags: angular, forms, reactive

Any value changes on a specific control is changing the entire form array indexes.

```
Form : {
"fundDetailsFormArray": [
{
  "conversionType": "Y",
  "amountGroup": {
    "fundIdAmount": null,
    "PercentShares": null
  }
},
{
  "conversionType": "Y",
  "amountGroup": {
    "fundIdAmount": null,
    "PercentShares": null
  }
},
{
  "conversionType": "Y",
  "amountGroup": {
    "fundIdAmount": null,
    "PercentShares": null
  }
}
]
}
```

Here, I have just changed the first index (conversionType) value to Y, but is getting reflected on all the array elements. 
PS: Iam initializing the formArray elements in onInit method. will this be a problem.

Comment: How are you updating values in `Form`? can you please reproduce same problem on stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem few days back. Initially, I was passing the FormGroup from my parent component and this was causing the issue. Instead i have pushed the FormGroup into the FormArray from the same component. Now, everything works fine.